# How to show that limiting value of the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2-xy}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}}$ is zero by $\epsilon-\delta $ definition

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality

I know that the limit of function when $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ is zero.
But how can I show this limiting value is correct using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit, i.e,
$$0<\sqrt{(x-x_{0})^2+(y-y_{0})^2}<\delta \implies |f(x,y)-L|<\epsilon$$
Now in my case, if I take 
$$\left|\frac{x^2-xy}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}}-0\right|<\epsilon$$
I dont know how to proceed further to get the $\delta.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A crucial observation is that
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{x^{2}-xy}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}}=x\cdot\dfrac{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}}=x(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}).
\end{align*}

Comment: Sir how can i proceed further to get $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$, where $\delta$ depends upon $\epsilon.$

Comment: So you choose $\delta=\min\{1,2\epsilon\}$, then $x,y\leq 1$ and hence $x(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})\leq 2x<2\delta<\epsilon$.

Comment: @user284331 One may include $x=y$ in the domain inasmuch as the discontinuity is removable.

Comment: Okay I see it now, thanks.